# Good at / better at

Tags: word-choice, difference

Which of the two options is the most appropriate one for this sentence?

> As to sports, I have played them my whole life. Certainly, I am **good at / better at** some of them such as tennis, football and water sports but I would be happy to try other sports as well if the need arises.

Comment: When comparing two options, the question is which **is more appropriate**. **Most appropriate** applies to three or more.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more appropriate to say *Certainly, I am better at some sports than I am at others* or *the ones I play most are tennis [etc].*

Answer (score 0):

*Better* is used when comparing things, whereas *good* is not. One can say "I am good at some sports, but better at others". One might also say "I am bad at tennis, but better at golf".

Your paragraph, using *good* works. It says you are good at some sports.

Your paragraph using *better* does not have an explicit comparison, but I would deduce the comparison from the sentence and the context. Making the comparison explicit might give

> As to sports, I have played them my whole life. Certainly, I am better at some of them such as tennis, football and water sports *than I am at others,* but I would be happy to try other sports as well if the need arises.

I would be happy with the *better* statement without the explicit comparison; I believe the comparison is understood. Which of the choices is preferable depends on what you are trying to say.